# Почему при многопоточности print иногда работает неправильно Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

С помощью ThreadPoolExecutor я в нескольких потоках ищу свободные порты, сканируя UPD, и вывожу их на консоль, как найду. Но при выводе почему-то некоторые появляются в одной строке. Как это можно исправить?
Пример:

```
UPD 993
UPD 992
UPD 994UPD  995

UPD 996
UPD 997
UPD 998UPD  999
```

Может как-то блокировать print?
`threading.Lock()` и `multiprocessing.Lock()` не помогают.

Comment: flush у принта не поможет ?

Comment: Лучше возвращайте эти значения в основной поток и печатайте их там. По-нормальному с интерфейсом должен работать только главный поток, а порождаемые потоки пусть занимаются работой. Синхронизировать вывод из разных потоков по идее можно, но этим вы съедите изрядную долю выгоды от использования потоков.

Comment: Заведите какой-нибудь файл и синхронизируйте потоки (скопее всего, в реальности, это процессы, т.е. порождение [fork()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)) используя [fcntl.lockf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html)

Comment: Если Lock не помогает, значит вы неправильно его используете

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356200/python-printing-in-multiple-threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, как написал CrazyElf, лучше (в моём случае) не выводить результат сразу на консоль, а добавлять в лист. В листе они, конечно, тоже будут расположены не по порядку, но его можно отсортировать (я так и сделал) и обойтись без лока.